# Why aren't messages from invalid senders filtered out by Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Example. I am receiving an email from Company X about my order number 123, 1 item USB cable, $ 12.50

I did not order anything at all so i click on reply, write my message, and send it.

After a few minutes i am receiving that famous email from the Mail Delivery Subsystem, that the address i send my email to, could not be found.
My attitude is: 'Return/Reply address unknown/non-existent? Do not even bother to deliver their email to me then. Period.

How to?

Comment: How to *what*? Please [edit]

Comment: Your posted is tagged *gmail*. Is this actually on your gmail address?

Comment: I'm not so happy with the latest edit, but can't revert it. We're not sure yet what the OP wants to ask (see my two earlier comments) and the editor has filled that in for the OP.

Comment: @JanDoggen Some edits are made in order to make the question on-topic. IMHO this is OK when those changes narrow the scope of the question to make it fit the site scope. If the OP doesn't like the change they could revert it (hopefully after they explain why they will do that). In this case the OP included [tag:gmail] instead of [tag:email]

Comment: I did edit the post a few times yes for reason that i missed 2 lines (i think it were 2 lines) of what i actually entered.

Answer (score 3):

That's just not how email works.

Email was invented during a time when there were a few dozen servers on the Internet, and pretty much everyone knew everyone else. There was no thought given to keeping email secure and to authenticate the sender, because it wasn't necessary.

There are a few schemes out there to try to authenticate accounts, but they're by no means universal and will probably add some unintended consequences.

It's just run-of-the-mill spam. Mark it as such and move on with your life.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you received [spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam).
There's probably a link in that mail that they want you to click on.

The *From* address for spam emails is often random, often fake (but sometimes looks like it's legitimate), that's why your reply [bounces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message).

Don't click the link. Don't reply either. Just delete the mail.

Whenever you get unsolicited email, don't even **open** it. Again, delete it.

---

Another possibility for bouncing replies is that a company that has your email address (maybe you did business with them in the past) is sending you mail with a *do not reply* from address, that intentionally is set up to bounce, because they do not (want to) monitor that mailbox.
This does not seem to be the case in your example. Usually these kinds of mails are offers for something, but what you describe (a reference to a non-existing order) is typical [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) spam.